# Benchmark code in specific unit in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, command-line-arguments, benchmarking, timeit

I previously used the `%timeit`- and `%%timeit`-magics in Juypter-Notebooks to benchmark parts of my code. My current problem is, that i would like to have `timeit`-output in the same unit, however [the available options](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) don't allow that.

I did a bit of research and found the `timeit`-module in the Python standard library. [There is a command-line interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface) for this module that allows exactly that:

```sh
python -m timeit --unit=msec 'for i in range(1000000): i**10'  # Prepend '!' to run in Jupyter
```

however the parts that i would want to benchmark are dependent on variables that exist in the scope of the Jupyter Notebook and are not directly passable to the `timeit`-call.

Are there ways to do this with the stdlib `timeit` or is there an alternative way to benchmark code-parts in a Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

According to docs, you cannot do it in the terminal:

`python -m timeit [-n N] [-r N] [-u U] [-s S] [-h] [statement ...]` - argument, that could test the block of code, is missing. Whereas directly in your working file (or test_you_name_it_file.py) it is possible to do.